# How can I find max and min value of every row

Tags: c++, arrays, max, min

My practice task is to find an array's index if the minimum value is higher than any other array's maximum value. If there are more than one, print only the lowest index. For example:
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
So the output is 2 because the 2nd row's minimum value is higher than the other row's maximum value. But im stuck at searching for min and max value of ***every*** array so I can't move on.

```
int numberOfTowns;
int numberOfDays;
cin >> numberOfTowns >> numberOfDays;
int temperature[100][100];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTowns; i++)
{
    int maxValue = temperature[i][0];
    int minValue = temperature[i][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfDays; j++)
    {
        cin >> temperature[i][j];

        if (temperature[i][j] > maxValue)
            maxValue = temperature[i][j];

        if (temperature[i][j] < minValue)
            minValue = temperature[i][j];

    }
        cout << "Max: " << maxValue << endl;
        cout << "Min: " << minValue << endl;
}
return 0;}
```

Edit: Just for clarification, numberOfTowns means number of rows basically and numberOfDays means number of columns.
My input & output looks like this:
(3 is number of rows and 5 is number of columns)

```
3 5

10 15 12 10 10
```

Max: 15
Min: 0

```
11 11 11 11 20
```

Max: 20
Min: 0

```
18 16 16 16 20
```

Max: 20
Min: 0

So my Max is working fine but my Min is always 0. Can anyone help with that?
P.S.: It's my first question here, and i am a bit new to C++, so sorry if I did something wrong.

Comment: what is "an array's index where the minimum value is higher than any other array's maximum value" ? At a given index there is only a single element, in the whole array there is only one minimum/maximum.

Comment: At `int maxValue = temperature[i][0];`, the value you are loading from the array is undefined. Looks like it's usually 0.

Comment: input is an array of arrays?

Comment: there is a [minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) algorithm to help you

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 At the end of the code, I will have to cout the index of the row, if the row applies to the condition. Condition is: minumum value is higher than any other row's maximum value

Comment: i dont understand the example input, when you have only two arrays, then either minimum in one is higher than the others max or not, what index are you looking for?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 this isnt the whole solution, because if you read ahead, you can see I said that I am stuck at finding min/max of every row. If I can get these then I can move on and try to solve the whole task. Imagine 3 rows:
1 2 3 4 5   //  
6 7 8 9 10   //  
11 12 13 14 15  //
( I dont know how to \n in comments  )   
Then the solution is 2 because you need the lowest index where the minValue is higher than an other's row maxValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `minValue` and `maxValue` with `temperature[i][0]` before writing anything into that position. Instead use the input value to initialize it:

```
    cin >> temperature[i][0];
    int maxValue = temperature[i][0];
    int minValue = temperature[i][0];
    for (int j = 1; j < numberOfDays; j++)    // start at 1 
    {
        cin >> temperature[i][j];

        if (temperature[i][j] > maxValue)
            maxValue = temperature[i][j];

        if (temperature[i][j] < minValue)
            minValue = temperature[i][j];

    }
```

Comment: Can you help me a bit further? So i got every array's max and min value. Now I have to compare an array's min value to every other arrays' max value. If the min is higher than the other row's max then i have to cout which array is that, I don't know how to compare a single element (MinValue) from a row to another row's single element (MaxValue). So for example:   
10 11 12 13 14  \n 
20 15 15 15 15  \n
10 10 16 10 10  \n
Solution is: 2 because the 2nd row's min is higher than the 1st row's max.

Comment: @Kevcso sorry I dont see the problem, put the min values in a vector, iteratate it and check the condition for each candidate. Note that comments arent for extended discussion. If you have another question, maybe open another question

Answer (score 0):

minValue is start from 0.
should start from 1st value.

```
int numberOfTowns;
int numberOfDays;
cin >> numberOfTowns >> numberOfDays;
int temperature[100][100];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTowns; i++)
{
    int maxValue;
    int minValue;
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfDays; j++)
    {
        cin >> temperature[i][j];

        if( j == 0 ) {
             maxValue = temperature[i][0];
             minValue = temperature[i][0];
             continue;
        }

        if (temperature[i][j] > maxValue)
            maxValue = temperature[i][j];

        if (temperature[i][j] < minValue)
            minValue = temperature[i][j];

    }
        cout << "Max: " << maxValue << endl;
        cout << "Min: " << minValue << endl;
}
return 0;}
```